# Set required RunTime in nuget package

Tags: xamarin, nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating two Nuget package using the official UI tool (a package contains .Net related utilities, the other contains Xamarin.Android stuff)https://docs.nuget.org/create/using-a-gui-to-build-packages

Now I need to set the minimum required Runtime (in my case 4.5). 
Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by runtime I am assuming you mean one of the assemblies in the NuGet package is compiled against .NET 4.5.

In NuGet Package Explorer create a directory:

```
lib\Net45
```

Then put the .NET 4.5 assembly or assemblies into that directory.

It looks like the NuGet Package Explorer supports creating a similar directory for Android.

```
lib\MonoAndroid
```

There is no version number here but all that means is the assembly should be considered compatible with any MonoAndroid version.